# Risky and dangerous

Tags: differences

Can you tell me the difference between risky and dangerous? It would be great if you could give me some specific examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please look up both words; if you have a question

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: *Risky* would describe someone's behavior while *dangerous* would describe a situation.  For example, "Her risky behavior sometimes got her into some dangerous situations." // A great way to see a nice variety of examples of usage is to look up each word in Linguee: http://www.linguee.com/

Answer (score 1):

The two words have very similar meanings. The main difference between the two is in the connotations (implied meanings) rather than denotations (explicit meanings.) [Risky](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/risky) can be defined as "full of the possibility of danger, failure or loss" and [dangerous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dangerous) can mean "likely to cause harm or injury" or "likely to cause problems or have adverse consequences."

Thesaurus entries for each word generally [include the other as a synonym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/dangerous), but there are some differences in common usage.

The word dangerous is more likely to be used to mean a situation that can result in actual injury or serious harm, while risky is more commonly used when talking about non-physical injury or loss, such as a financial investment, social interaction, emotional pain, etc.

For example, if you're talking about jumping into the ocean with a bunch of sharks, you'd probably call that dangerous, rather than risky. If you were gambling, betting on an unlikely outcome in hopes of a big payout would be called risky, not dangerous. Driving is dangerous, while buying a used car is risky.

Risky is more likely to be used to mean there's a high probability of something going wrong, regardless of what kind of consequences there may be.

*Dangerous* is more likely to be used when the consequences are serious, and especially when they involve injury or serious property damage.

Answer (score 0):

[Dangerous: able or likely to cause harm or injury. / likely to cause problems or to have adverse consequences.](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20dangerous&oq=definition%20of%20dangerous&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6612j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Risky: full of the possibility of danger, failure, or loss.](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20dangerous&oq=definition%20of%20dangerous&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6612j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=definition%20of%20risky)

They are very similar words that can **very often be used interchangeably**, however,

- 'risky' is more broadly used for types of risks that might not cause bodily
  injury to the point it can be vague what is at risk unless specified
- 'dangerous' is so often
  associated with bodily harm that applying it to something with small
  circumstances might seem overstated unlesss a lesser consequence is specified

Here are two sentences where both words work well:

> Walking across the lake with thin ice is risky
>
> Walking across the lake with thin ice is dangerous.

In a case like that, both words can apply and seem to mean nearly the same thing.
Something bad for the presumed *person* walking is suggested with either.

However, a shorter sentence like:

> A lake with thin ice is risky.(not so good use of risky)

The lake isn't taking any risks. This is a bit vague and not idiomatic even if not grammatically wrong. Walking across a lake is risky however because people walk, and people falling in an icy lake is not a vague reference.

You could say:

> A lake with thin ice is dangerous.(fine use)

It is a situation that could likely do harm to someone.

> Balancing the eggs on your head is risky. (yes, you are risking breaking the eggs clearly)

You're risking braking the eggs through the risky maneuver.

> Balancing the eggs on your head is dangerous.(not really a good use)

Well, dangerous for what? No one is going to get hurt.

One last example: they don't put up road signs that say **"Risky curve ahead"** but they do put up signs that say **"Dangerous curve ahead"**